# How to populate a field of subsetted data from master data in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a subset of SNP data with rs ids (and other fields) and I want to create two new columns with their respective chromosome number and chromosome location. I have a master file with ALL SNPs (rs ids, chromosome number, locations... etc) and I want to populate my file from the master file using the command line (my subsetted file has ~3 million rows).

I was thinking something like join, and if then statement, or awk (or some combination of these)

FOR EXAMPLE, What I have:

file1

```
SNP A1  A2  Freq1.Hapmap    b   se  p   N
rs1000000   G   A   0.6333  1e-04   0.0043  0.9814  233572
rs10000010  T   C   0.575   -0.0022 0.0029  0.4384  339148
```

file2

```
ID  SNP Chromosome  Position    REF Allele  ALT Allele  Contig  Contig Position Band    dbSNP
chr10:1175426:C/G:1 rs1000000   chr10   1175426 C   G   GL000093.1  1115426 p15.3   rs184435191
chr10:31133635:T/C:1    rs143579887 chr10   31133635    T   C   GL000093.1  31073635    p11.23  rs143579887
chr10:33247334:G/T:1    chr10:33247334:G/T:1    chr10   33247334    G   T   GL000093.1  33187334    p11.22  
chr11:118230335:A/G:1   rs10000010  chr11   118230335   A   G   GL000104.1  21792751    q23.3   rs147754044
chr11:132968833:A/C:1   chr11:132968833:A/C:1   chr11   132968833   A   C   GL000104.1  36531249    q25 
chr11:57678793:C/G:-1   rs77482717  chr11   57678793    C   G   GL000103.1  2984588 q12.1   rs77482717
chr11:61722645:C/A:1    chr11:61722645:C/A:1    chr11   61722645    C   A   GL000103.1  7028440 q12.3   rs1109748
```

What I want:

```
SNP Chromosome  Position A1 A2  Freq1.Hapmap    b   se  p   N
        rs1000000   chr10   1175426 G   A   0.6333  1e-04   0.0043  0.9814  233572
        rs10000010  chr11   118230335 T C   0.575   -0.0022 0.0029  0.4384  339148
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your files are tab separated:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3 OFS $4;next}{$2=a[$1] OFS $2}1' file2 file1
SNP Chromosome  Position    A1  A2  Freq1.Hapmap    b   se  p   N
rs1000000   chr10   1175426 G   A   0.6333  1e-04   0.0043  0.9814  233572
rs10000010  chr11   118230335   T   C   0.575   -0.0022 0.0029  0.4384  339148
```

for all records in `file2`: associate each SNP with corresponding Chromosome and Position values in an array, `file1`: retrieve Chromosome and Position values associated with each SNP from the array and insert before second column.

Comment: Thanks so much for you suggestion. This seemed to create the correct column headers, but did not populate the columns. They are blank.

Comment: Ah, I think I found my issue. Thank you!!

Comment: My master file had a download issue, so it was not a problem with the command.